# Want to make pen pressure viewer with Python

Tags: python, pyqt, tablet, qevent, wacom

I want to make a pen pressure viewer with Python. It's working in that window:

[image]

but it's not working when I'm drawing in Photoshop or just other software.

How can I make it work when I'm drawing in other windows?

```
import os, time, sys, subprocess
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class PressureBar(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.pen_pressure = 0
        frame_rect = app.desktop().frameGeometry()
        self.progress = QProgressBar(self)
        self.resize(300, 30)
        self.progress.setGeometry(0, 0, 300, 25)
        self.progress.setMaximum(100)
        self.setWindowTitle("Pen Pressure Viewer")
        
    def tabletEvent(self, tabletEvent):
        self.pen_pressure = int(tabletEvent.pressure() * 100)

        if(tabletEvent.type() == QTabletEvent.TabletPress):
            self.penIsDown = True

        self.progress.setValue(self.pen_pressure)
        tabletEvent.accept()
        self.update()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
myWindow = PressureBar()
myWindow.show()
app.exec()
```

Comment: Could you give us some more details as to what isn't working? saying "It's not working" is very vague. Is it throwing an error? what is the unwanted behaviour?

Comment: well it's working fine when i'm drawing in that window (with a pen), but when i'm drawing other software(like photoshop,or some other drawing software). nothing change pen pressure value viewer. so it's only working in that window...

Comment: sorry about my bad english. i wanna show what i mean... [link](https://youtu.be/NMSgt96Lsg4)

Comment: I can't comment since I just joined recently, but I think because the class parameter is a QWidget, it only functions inside of it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a Wacom tablet? In their official documents, they say, tablet sends the value only to the active window.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35666116)